# Can I get [0 0] from Categorical Labeling in CNN's?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

From what I understand from keras labeling, one hot encoding does not permit the values to be [0 0]? is this assumption correct?

We are trying to classify 2 classes and we want to be able to detect garbage when a garbage image is fed. However, it always detects either 
[0 1] or [1 0]. Is it possible to get [0 0] as a label without introducing a class the will handle the garbage or no?

So basically, can the CNN predict it to be something else if its not the 2 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not be possible.  Your "garbage" would be a third class, requiring labels of [1 0 0], [0 1 0], and [0 0 1].

Very simply, the model you've described will return one of two categories, whichever has a higher rating in your final layer.  This happens whether the input values are 0.501 and 0.499, or 0.011 and 0.010 with a large "not sure" portion.  If you don't explicitly code "not sure" into your model, then that portion of the decision will not be considered in the classification.

Comment: However I think OP don't have such images and thus will not be able to train such model. I'm guessing OP is in a situation that's like doing sentiment analysis where there's a probability range (say 0.4-0.6) that the model is not too sure about the correct class of the input image.

Comment: @YilunZhang yes we are doing something similar where if we are in the probability range lets say 0.4 or less then we consider it garbage. 

However, I think we could also think about doing it as Prune said. 

we just fed random images that we would classify as garbage images

Comment: @SonGoku If you are able to add/augment your training data to add the third label, then you should definitely do that. That will be able to solve your problem. I didn't know that you can add extra data for the 3rd label.

Comment: @ Yilun Zhang regarding sentiment analysis, what do you think would be the best approach just in case we need to do something like that?

Comment: @SonGoku: your question on sentiment analysis is not part of this question, and is too general for Stack Overflow.  Please move it to an appropriate site or a chat room.

Comment: Thank you @Prune for the insight.